# Cannot read property 'startLineNumber' of undefined after pressing Alt+F12 in VS Code, F#

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

I receive the following message when trying to do "Peek definition" action. Sometimes it shows me a warning and other times error with the same text. Any suggestions?

PS. Using the latest version of Visual Studio Code with F# plugins (FAKE, fsharp, Paket)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug that you should file on the repo of the responsible F# extension.